# Syncing entities from two different data providers?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

This might be a duplicate but I couldn't find appropriate solution,

**Server:**

- SQL Server
- Entity Framework
- WCF Service

**Client**

- SQLite
- Entity Framework for SQLite
- WPF

**Requirements**

I've few common tables in the server and in the client with same table name and same column names.

My task is to delete the data from the client tables and copy the data from the server tables by calling it through my WPF application.

**Possible Solutions**

1. Using Microsoft's Sync framework (but data providers are different
   so, it may or may not work)
2. Using traditional approach (removing entity framework) & use Datasets instead.

Are there any better solutions to achieve this Sync functionality?